# why doesn't my banner appear in Linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, ads, banner, banner-ads

I am using relative layout in linear layout.My banner appears on the design screen, but no ads appear when I run my application.I looked at many examples but I could not find.My application was horizontal before now I'm designing vertically.Previously I was using Relativelayout then my banner was working.Here my code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="12"
   android:background="#fffdd0">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_double"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/xx"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fiftyfifty"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/skip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_countdown2x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_double" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_countdown50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_yariyariya"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_countdownNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_skip"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_countdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="00:30"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_pop_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_countdown1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_kalp1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kalp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_satinal"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:onClick="satinalMain"
        android:background="@drawable/satinal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_kalp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="3">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_soru"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_a"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_b"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_a"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_c"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_b"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_d"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_c"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_infoA"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/info"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gec"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_skor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="SKOR :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reklam"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus"
        android:onClick="startVideoAd"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_kalp_kazan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="İzle Kazan"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3101578796185185/4912585915">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `RelativeLayout` nested inside your `LinearLayout`? Pick one of these as your top level. Deeply nested layouts like this have very poor performance. I suggest you rework your layout to be more shallow and still get the same behavior you want. You should be able to do a single `RelativeLayout` with all of the widgets directly inside it. I also suggest checking out `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `bannerview` is lower than your screen! (Maybe you're using this layout for a fragment and your activity has a toolbar, am I right?)

Just put `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout design is not very well done, the buttons at the center (first RelativeLayout) are not constrained to the adjacent buttons, so they may overlap.

You should use a `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, the later is obsolete now.

You have several items with `wrap_content` height inside a layout that you want to stretch vertically, which is contradictory. This may cause views inside the inner RelativeLayouts to be hidden if they are smaller than the height.

`weightSum` is a property that is rarely useful because weights are calculated automatically, you should simply know that two views with 1 and 1 with use  50% each, and if you add another with weight 2 it will have proportionally that weight. So it will end up 25%, 25% and 50%.

There is no need to place the AdView inside a RelativeLayout if it is the only view there.

If you want the banner to be always visible, then simply place a default height (either `wrap_content` or a given height in dps). The other views will use the remaining space to calculate the `weight` space.

I recommend you to first study how different Layouts work before attempting to build your screen layout.

On the other hand, the AdView requires some additional configuration on your end to become shown, because if you did not setup some campaign to be shown, the view won't display anything.

Comment: I am not an expert in design.The reason I ask questions on this platform is just to learn.I'm here because I don't know like everyone.I'm just investigating the cause of the problem.but I think people's purpose is to judge.Thank you for your answer

Comment: @UgurGul I'm sorry if you felt that rude. I didn't judge, It's a fact that the layout is not well designed and have several flaws there (addressed in the answer), which are the cause of your problem. it's a real advice to study (takes an hour at most) how layouts work before trying to create a layout with that many views.

Comment: `AdView` is some steps more advanced , so you will have better foundations if you first understand the basics . If not, you may fall later under common errors which otherwise may give you trouble to understand and solve.